# Stochastic calculus of Gaussian white noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I see a strange stochastic integral and don't know how to proceed?

Denote $\xi$ a Gaussian white noise,

Denote

$$I(n)=\int_t^{t+n\Delta t}ds\int_t^sd\xi$$
How to prove that $<I(1)I(1)>= \frac{1}{3}\Delta t^3$ and $<I(1)I(2)>= \frac{5}{6}\Delta t^3$?

Specifically, can anyone explain how to deal with these kind of integrals generally? Routine stochastic integral often only deals with Brownian motion. Any references and books are also greatly appreciated.

These equations are taken from a theoretical physics paper.

Many thanks!

Comment: how's your gaussian white noise defined? is it a Hida distibution? do you have some reference  for this?

Comment: @Chaos, I am mainly referring to this paper (Eq. S11-17). I believe they follow normal definition but the integral puzzles me. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David_Brueckner/publication/339323633_Inferring_the_dynamics_of_underdamped_stochastic_systems/links/5eb2765b299bf152d69dc306/Inferring-the-dynamics-of-underdamped-stochastic-systems.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE:
may you know that $(\Delta B(t))^2\sim \Delta t$ when $B(t)$ is brownian motion.I wish It helps you. so
$$\int_t^{t+n\Delta t}1ds=n\Delta t=o(\Delta t)$$and
$$\int_t^sd\xi\sim \sum \Delta B(t)=o(\sqrt{\Delta t})$$so It seems that $$I(n)=o(\sqrt{\Delta t}).o(\Delta t)=o(\Delta t^{\frac32})$$ can you proceed  now ?

Comment: Hi Khosrotash, Thank you so much for your answer! Your intuition is really helpful but I am wondering since the inner integral generally depends on s, I am not sure why it can be treated as two independent integral. I apologize for my notation, but I actually mean a double integral instead of two integral with simple multiplication.

Comment: @Alex: you're welcome. I made it to discretize the approach.